# How to use boost::unit_test?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I'm trying to learn how to test programs so I tried Boost. I've started reading it and [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/test/doc/html/tutorials/new-year-resolution.html) I've met this line:

*Now I can compile it and link with the **unit test framework***.
From where and how am I suppose to get unit test framework? And what it is?
 I just do not know what to eat it with. Could someone please provide some steps how to use it or maybe point me to some other tutorials where even simplest things like unit test framework and how to link it with will be explained.
Thanks

Comment: The tutorial on http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/test/doc/html/tutorials/new-year-resolution.html is weird. The e-mail at the beginning of the page http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/test/doc/html/tutorials/intro-in-testing.html is dead. And it seems that author even have not compiled the code, the terrible macro BOOST_AUTO_EST_CASE (missed letter) used on the page http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/test/doc/html/tutorials/new-year-resolution.html

Comment: All fixed with Boost 1.60+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a fast comment. The problem with this library is that it has at least three different ways of implementing and running the tests. Depending on what `#defines` you add to your code before including the boost unit test header, it can automatically generate a main function for you (and then build a complete program that executes the tests you've defined), or rely on external test runners.

Read carefully those running modes to know what to do. Usually, the easiest way is to do this:

- Include your tests in a .cpp file.
- Before including the unit test header file, define the preprocessor macro `BOOST_TEST_MAIN` (this will define a main function that will run the tests)
- Link your program against the libboost-unit-test DLL (this is system dependant).

Your program will execute the tests defined, thank to the automatically generated main function.

Comment: This is not a problem. This is feature ;)

Comment: Gennadiy, can you please take a look to my comment to the question?